# How can I get from Panama City to Rivas, in Nicaragua?

Tags: buses, panama, nicaragua

We are trying to get from Panama City to Rivas (Nicaragua) next week.
The flights are too expensive and we don't mind travelling non-stop by bus.

What options do we have?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Panam%C3%A1/Rivas) shows there is a bus Panama City - San Jose, Costa Rica twice a day and San Jose, Costa Rica - Rivas five times per day. The first one should cost 50 - 95 USD, second one 30 - 45 USD (in total 80 - 140 USD). First one takes 16 hours, second one 6:30 hours.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [travel planning website](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Panam%C3%A1/Rivas), there are no non-stop buses that go from Panama City to Rivas, the only bus option has one stop in San Jose. The only non-stop option - at least presented by this website - is to drive.